# Realm update async slow

Tags: android, realm

I'm updating my object (an object with 40-50 fields, but I update only 5-6) in an async transaction.

Somewhy, the `commit` of the transaction (I mean the time from the last row in execute to the `onSuccess()` call), takes around 5 seconds.

I update only one object and only some fields. What Am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Intervention i = realm.where(Intervention.class).equalTo("ID", openedIntervention.getInterventionID()).findFirst();
                if (i != null) {
                    i.setULTIMA_LETTURA_VECCHIO_MISURATORE(etOldMeterReading.getText() == null ? null : etOldMeterReading.getText().toString());
                    i.setLAST_UPDATE(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    i.setMISURATORE_INSTALLATO_ID(etOldMeter.getTag() == null ? null : etOldMeter.getTag().toString());
                    if (etOldMeter.getTag() == null || etOldMeter.getTag().toString().isEmpty() || etOldMeter.getTag().toString().equals(RuntimeHelper.emptyUUIDString)) {
                        i.setMISURATORE_INSTALLATO(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fine save");
                if (alsoLoad)
                    loadData();

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable error) {
                Log.d("TAG", "MSG", error);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Errore durante il salvataggio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

It should be a pretty simple query, but I don't understand where the blocking operation is coming from.

Thanks all

Comment: 50 fields for a single object? Maybe you should reconsider your schema and create some sub-objects in 1:1 relation that contain those 6 fields only.

Comment: Thanks for replying but using db objects with only 6 fields each is not a good solution.. SQL db tables might have hundreds of fields, and this is not a problem.. my app is using SQL tables and I already filter only the one I need.. believe me, 50 are not many and not a problem :)

Comment: "sql can do this, sql can do that" realm is not sql

Comment: Actually, I think `loadData()` is the problem, not the async write -- also, is this async write done in a loop? o_o

Comment: @Pawel having 50 fields is better than having 1:1 relations when you're working with a NoSQL DB, especially Realm. 1:1 relations would mean now you need to manage cascade deletion

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for replying, the time elapses between the end of execute and the start of loadData(), so I'm not understanding why it takes so much for such a small operation; looks like the time is wasted in the commit of the transaction. btw it's a "one-shot" operation, not looped :)

Comment: @TimCastelijns true, but as EpicPandaForce pointed out realm is not really performant with relations. I did this example only to explain that 50 fields are not really that many in a medium-big project